# Hide some datetimes in a query

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a query that returns me this result:

```
-----DATE--------------VALUE1---VALUE2
|2016-09-20 11:15:00| 5653856 | 37580
|2016-09-20 11:16:00|  NULL      NULL
|2016-09-20 11:18:00|  NULL      NULL
|2016-09-20 11:20:00|  NULL      NULL
|2016-09-20 11:30:00| 5653860  37580
|2016-09-20 11:32:00|  NULL      NULL
|2016-09-20 11:34:00|  NULL      NULL
```

In this table, only the records in xx:00, xx:15, xx:30, xx:45, have values, other records are null.

How can I make a condition in my query to get only 00,15,30 and 45 times records and dont show the others?

This is the query:

```
SELECT t.date, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '924' THEN t.value END) - MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '925' THEN t.valueEND) as IMA_71,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '930' THEN t.value END) as IMA_73 
FROM records t 
where office=10 
      and date between '2016-09-20 11:15:00' and '2016-10-21 11:15:00' 
GROUP BY t.office,t.date order by t.date asc;
```

Comment: `where value1 is null and value2 is null`?

Comment: it doesnt work for me becouse it isnt a simple query

Comment: This is the query:

Comment: `SELECT t.date, MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '924' THEN t.value END)- MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '925' THEN t.valueEND) as IMA_71,MAX(CASE WHEN t.id= '930' THEN t.value END) as IMA_73 FROM records t where office=10 and date between '2016-09-20 11:15:00' and '2016-10-21 11:15:00' GROUP BY t.office,t.date order by t.date asc;`

Comment: Do **not** post code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to determine the minute, and filter on that:

```
where  extract('minute' from t.date) in (0, 15, 30, 45)
```